# How to make batch request for adset metrics

Tags: php, facebook, batch-processing, facebook-marketing-api

I have a list of about 260 campaign ID's and I want to get all the adset data for each campaign ID.

I am using the following to make a request for one campaign ID but if I run this in a loop and very quickly reach my user request limit.

```
$campaign = new AdCampaign($campaign_id);
$adsets = $campaign->getAdSets($fields);
```

I am following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/chapter-6-ads-management#sets and currently using what they suggest:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;

$fields = array(
  AdSetFields::NAME,
  AdSetFields::START_TIME,
  AdSetFields::END_TIME,
  AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET,
  AdSetFields::LIFETIME_BUDGET,
);

$campaign = new AdCampaign('<CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID>');
$adsets = $campaign->getAdSets($fields);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Facebook's batch request methods to request fields for each campaign https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#multiple_methods

The [PHP Ads SDK does not support FB batch requests using its object wrappers](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/issues/77) but you can use the general API wrapper easily enough. For example:

```
$response = $api->call('/', 'POST', array('batch' => $json_string));
```

Where $api is an instance of Facebook\Api and $json_string is a JSON-encoded array of batch operation requests for adset fields. The JSON should look like the following example (using API version 2.4 and made-up campaign group IDs 1000001 and 1000002):

```
[
    { "method": "GET", 
      "relative_url":"v2.4/1000001?fields=name,start_time,end_time,daily_budget,lifetime_budget"
    },
    { "method": "GET", 
      "relative_url":"v2.4/1000002?fields=name,start_time,end_time,daily_budget,lifetime_budget"
    }
]
```

Comment: I might be getting confused but how do I pass in multiple <CAMPAIGN_GROUP_ID>'s? They will all be GET requests so perhaps I have got the wrong idea and don't need to use a batch request?

Comment: I updated the sample code example to show multiple GET requests in the batch request. If this answer works for you I'd appreciate if you'd mark it as accepted.

Comment: FB Ads SDK for PHP now supports batch requests, here's an example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_batch_request